# Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'providerID'

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with the newest version of FirebaseAuth 5.0 this is my code:

```
if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {          
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if error == nil {
           if let user = user {
               if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                  let userData = ["provider": user.providerID] as [String: Any]
```

problem is "Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no value "ProviderID" " But in firebase 4 this method worked. Thanks!

Comment: Can you ask complete questions? Not clear what are you asking here.

Comment: just made it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AuthDataResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthDataResult) has a property user that has `providerID`. You shouldn't consider `AuthDataResult` as `user` in the `completion`. You can access the `providerId` as below,

```
if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {          
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authData, error) in
        if error == nil {
           if let user = authData?.user {
               if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                  let userData = ["provider": user.providerID] as [String: Any]
```

Comment: thank you!!!!! but can you explain why I shouldn't consider user in the completion?

Comment: You can use `user` or anything but its type will remain `AuthDataResult` that has the property user (i.e, `FIRUser`) so `providerID` should be accessed on a `FIRUser` object. For example, if you name `AuthDataResult` as `user` then this statement `if let user = authData?.user` in above sample will change to `if let user = user?.user`.